# iOS UIWebView load xml

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have an App Store review pages of XML address (http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=350962117/sortBy=mostRecent/xml). I want to put them on the iPhone to show them as feeds.

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=350962117/sortBy=mostRecent/xml";
```

But webView does not show this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

must add **webView** in your **nib** and connect **webView** **delegate** methods
**FileName**: **WebViewController**.**m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 

{

NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.google.com”;


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];


NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

hope your helpfull...